# Content of file in Visual Studio sometimes became gray

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I use VS2013 for my project. I use TFS for manage source code, sometime I don't know why content of a file in my project be gray. And all references to the class in this file was lost

Please help me how to resolve in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In solution explorer Right click that file --> Exclude from project --> Rebuild. Then Include this file again. Your problem will be solved. Good luck